# Why is my div going out of its parent div when the screen is resized?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, position

I'm working on a personal portfolio in pure html/css only and was trying to make the site responsive by using media queries. Below is code showing two sections of my portfolio.

My problem is with the worked-dash class div. When the window is resized below the width of the worked-dash, the worked-dash div goes outside of it's parent div instead of resizing automatically.

The mind-boggling thing is that my other div, about-dash, works perfectly fine. So I will include the code for comparison. Here is the codepen for the [About-dash working as intended](https://codepen.io/codak_blacc/pen/bGjBjWY?editors=1100) and the [problematic worked-dash.](https://codepen.io/codak_blacc/pen/PoBbdZa) Be sure to change the orientation of the codepen view and to resize the viewport to below 420px to see the difference.

Screenshot of about-dash working as intended:

[image]

Code:

```css
:root {
    --background:#f8f9fa;
    --about-info-text-color:#f8f9fa;
    --sec-worked-background-color:#003772;
    --org-description-background-color:#0456ad;
    --org-description-boxshadow:#0169d8;
    --org-description\job-tasks-text-color:#f8f9fa;
    --projects-description-background-color:#FFFFFF;
    --projects-description-boxshadow:#eaeaea;
    --card-project-title-background-color:#003772;
    --card-project-title-text-color:#f8f9fa;
    --work-duration-color:#68abf1;
    --footer-background-color:#003772;
    --footer-heading:#f8f9fa;
    --socials-background-color:#f8f9fa;
    --footnote-text-color:#68abf1;
    --memoji-background:#d3d5d6;
    --memoji-shadow:#d3d5d6;
    --anchor-accents:#3083DC;
    --anchor-opacity: 48,131,220;/*Decimal RGB version of the above color*/
    --title-color:#FFFFFF;
    --title-background:#3083dc;
    --title-accent:#0051a8;
    --shadow:#d4d4d4;
    --JetBrains:'JetBrains Mono', monospace;
    --Roboto:'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

/*Normalization*/
*,
::before,
::after {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
}

.sec-about {
    width:100%;
    height:103vh;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color:#003772;
}

.about-center {
    width:1170px;
    padding:75px 20px 23px 50px;
    height:fit-content;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    margin-top:0px;
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.about_me_title {
    font-family: var(--Roboto);
    width: fit-content;
    padding:10px 5px;
    position:relative;
    top:-50px;
    background-color:var(--title-background);
    color:var(--title-color);
    box-shadow:7px 7px var(--title-accent);
    font-size:2em;
}

.about-dash {
    width:70%;
    height:5px;
    background-color:var(--anchor-accents);
    position:relative;
    left:170px;
    top:-20px;
}

.about-info {
    padding-right: 10px;
    font-family: var(--Roboto);
    text-align: justify;
    color:var(--about-info-text-color);
}


/************************************************RESPONSIVE-DESIGN******************************************/
  
  @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width:420px) {

    html {
        background-color: red;
    }

    /* About Section */

    .sec-about {
        height:100%;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: flex-start;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .about-center {
        margin-top:30px;
        width:100%;
        height:fit-content;
        flex-direction: column;
        padding: 0px;
        border-radius:0px;
    }

    .about-info {
        height:200px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        font-family: var(--Roboto);
        text-align: justify;
        color:var(--about-info-text-color);
        width:90%;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .about-dash {
        width: 60%;
        height:5px;
        background-color:var(--anchor-accents);
        margin-top:-10px;
        position: relative;
        top:20px;
        left:120px;
    }

    .about_me_title {
        width: fit-content;
        padding:10px 5px;
        position: relative;
        top:50px;
        margin-top: -60px;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        background-color:var(--title-background);
        color:var(--title-color);
        box-shadow:7px 7px var(--title-accent);
        font-size:1.25em;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".\style.css"/>
    <title>Portfolio V1</title>
    <!--JetBrains Mono Font-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=JetBrains+Mono:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Roboto Font-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>
    <header class="Header"></header>
        <main>
        <section class="sec-about">
            <div class="about-center">
                <article class="about-info">
                    <div class="about-dash"></div>
                    <h2 class="about_me_title">About Me</h2>
                </article>
            </div>
        </section>
</main>
</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot of worked-dash breaking out of it's parent div:

[image]

Code:

```css
:root {
    --background:#f8f9fa;
    --about-info-text-color:#f8f9fa;
    --sec-worked-background-color:#003772;
    --org-description-background-color:#0456ad;
    --org-description-boxshadow:#0169d8;
    --org-description\job-tasks-text-color:#f8f9fa;
    --projects-description-background-color:#FFFFFF;
    --projects-description-boxshadow:#eaeaea;
    --card-project-title-background-color:#003772;
    --card-project-title-text-color:#f8f9fa;
    --work-duration-color:#68abf1;
    --footer-background-color:#003772;
    --footer-heading:#f8f9fa;
    --socials-background-color:#f8f9fa;
    --footnote-text-color:#68abf1;
    --memoji-background:#d3d5d6;
    --memoji-shadow:#d3d5d6;
    --anchor-accents:#3083DC;
    --anchor-opacity: 48,131,220;/*Decimal RGB version of the above color*/
    --title-color:#FFFFFF;
    --title-background:#3083dc;
    --title-accent:#0051a8;
    --shadow:#d4d4d4;
    --JetBrains:'JetBrains Mono', monospace;
    --Roboto:'Roboto', sans-serif;
}


/*Normalization*/
*,
::before,
::after {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: #f8f9fa;
}

.sec-worked {
    background-color:var(--sec-worked-background-color);
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width:100%;
    height:103vh;
}

.container-worked {
    margin-top: 0px;
    width:1100px;
    height:650px;
}

.worked-title {
    font-family: var(--Roboto);
    background-color:var(--title-background);
    color:var(--title-color);
    width:fit-content;
    padding:10px 5px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px var(--title-accent);
    font-size:2em;
}


.worked-dash {
    width:60%;
    height:5px;
    background-color:var(--anchor-accents);
    position:relative;
    left:290px;
    top:-89px;
}

/************************************************RESPONSIVE-DESIGN******************************************/
  
  @media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width:420px) {
    
    /* General */

    html {
        background-color:red;
    }

    /* Work Section */

    .sec-worked {
        background-color:var(--sec-worked-background-color);
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        padding-bottom: 60px;
        margin:0px;
    }
    
    .container-worked {
        margin-top: 60px;
        width:100%;
        height: 20%;
    }
    
    .worked-title {
        font-family: var(--Roboto);
        background-color:var(--title-background);
        color:var(--title-color);
        width:fit-content;
        padding:10px 5px;
        margin-bottom: 60px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        box-shadow: 7px 7px var(--title-accent);
        font-size:1.25em;
    }
    
    .worked-dash {
        width:50%;
        height:5px;
        background-color:var(--anchor-accents);
        position:relative;
        left:200px;
        top:-81px;
        margin: 0px;
    }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".\style.css"/>
    <title>Portfolio V1</title>
    <!--JetBrains Mono Font-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=JetBrains+Mono:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Roboto Font-->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body>

    <header class="Header"></header>
        
    <main>
        <section class="sec-worked">
            <div class="container-worked">
                <h2 class="worked-title">Where I've worked</h2>
                <div class="worked-dash"></div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It looks like because your worked-dash is set to 60% and your worked-title is set to fit-content, at low screen sizes, the worked-title element is greater than 40% of the container-worked div so the elements overflow.

Comment: @Adam hmmm...but in the about-dash, if you "force" it to overflow, it does so without exposing the red background (html background is set to red). The whole idea was that in a larger display because there will be more room, the dash would take up the extra space. If I set the work dash to lower than 60% it'll leave unnecessary room in larger displays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I've done. I've made `.container-worked` a flex box container and set the width to 90% of the full screen width. This means that there's always a gap on the right hand side of it. I've also used `align-items: center` so that you don't need to use relative positioning to centre the dash. I've then used `flex-grow` on the worked-dash flex item to ensure it always expands to fill up the width of the parent div.

If you use that approach at smaller screen sizes it'll still fit so there's no need for media queries. Hope this helps. If it's not what you're looking for drop me a comment below.

```css
:root {
  --sec-worked-background-color: #003772;
  --anchor-accents: #3083dc;
  --title-color: #ffffff;
  --title-background: #3083dc;
  --title-accent: #0051a8;
  --JetBrains: "JetBrains Mono", monospace;
  --Roboto: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

/*Normalization*/
*,
::before,
::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box; /* moved this from html rule so it applies on all elements */
}

body {
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
}

.sec-worked {
  background-color: var(--sec-worked-background-color);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* put the element in the center of the div vertically */
  height: 103vh;
}

.container-worked {
  width:90%; /* Set this at 90% so there's a gap on the RHS of the container */
  gap: 1rem; /* put a gap between each element */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* this means we can vertically align the worked-dash element in the worked-title div. */
}

.worked-title {
  font-family: var(--Roboto);
  background-color: var(--title-background);
  color: var(--title-color);
  padding: 10px 5px;
  box-shadow: 7px 7px var(--title-accent);
  font-size: 2em;
}

.worked-dash {
  height: 5px;
  flex-grow:1; /* added this so that this element always expands to fill the width of the parent div */
  background-color: var(--anchor-accents);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="sec-worked">
    <div class="container-worked">
      <h2 class="worked-title">Where I've worked</h2>
      <div class="worked-dash"></div>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Hey @Adam, ok so I finally got it working. I took your solution and tweaked it a little. I removed the positioning from my side and utilized the align-items:center and display:flex on the respective divs just as you had put. I also took your advice on the box-sizing. Works perfectly. Thanks for taking the time to help me out much appreciated!

Comment: My pleasure Andy. Glad you got it sorted 